# Error handling of python subprocess to run bash script with multiple input arguments vs successful running of bash script with hardcoded inputs

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, subprocess

I have a Rest API to execute `curl` command in bash script to retrieve newspaper information from a national library website as follows. I can run this bash script in two different ways:

1. `$ bash sof.sh # input arguments are hardcoded! WORKS OK!`
2. `$ python file.py # input arguments are passed from a dictionary! ERROR!`

Here is `sof.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

: '
################## 1) Running via Bash Script & hardcoding input arguments ##################
myQUERY="Rusanen"
myORDERBY="DATE_DESC"
myFORMATS='["NEWSPAPER"]'
myFUZZY="false"
myPubPlace='["Iisalmi", "Kuopio"]'
myLANG='["FIN"]'
################## 1) Running via Bash Script & hardcoding input arguments ##################
# Result: OK! a json file with retreived expected information
'

#: '
################## 2) Running from python script with input arguments ##################
for ARGUMENT in "$@"
do
    #echo "$ARGUMENT"
     KEY=$(echo $ARGUMENT | cut -f1 -d=)
     KEY_LENGTH=${#KEY}
     VALUE="${ARGUMENT:$KEY_LENGTH+1}"
     export "$KEY"="$VALUE"
done
echo $# "ARGS:" $*
################## 2) Running from python script with input arguments ##################
# Result: Error!!
#'

out_file_name="newspaper_info_query_${myQUERY// /_}.json"

echo ">> Running $0 | Searching for QUERY: $myQUERY | Saving in $out_file_name"

curl 'https://digi.kansalliskirjasto.fi/rest/binding-search/search/binding?offset=0&count=10000' \
-H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Pragma: no-cache' \
--compressed \
--output $out_file_name \
-d @- <<EOF
{   "query":"$myQUERY",
    "languages":$myLANG,
    "formats":$myFORMATS,
    "orderBy":"$myORDERBY",
    "fuzzy":$myFUZZY,
    "publicationPlaces": $myPubPlace
}
EOF
```

Running `$ bash sof.sh` with manually hardcoded input arguments in the bash script works fine with expected behavior, i.e., it returns a json file with expected information.

However, to automate my code, I need to run this bash script using `$ python file.py` with `subprocess` as follows:

```
def rest_api_sof(params={}):    
    params = {'query':            ["Rusanen"], 
              'publicationPlace': ["Iisalmi", "Kuopio"], 
              'lang':             ["FIN"], 
              'orderBy':          ["DATE_DESC"], 
              'formats':          ["NEWSPAPER"], 
              }

    print(f"REST API: {params}")

    subprocess.call(['bash',
                     'sof.sh',
                     f'myFORMATS={params.get("formats", "")}',
                     f'myQUERY={",".join(params.get("query"))}',
                     f'myORDERBY={",".join(params.get("orderBy", ""))}',
                     f'myLANG={params.get("lang", "")}',
                     f'myPubPlace={params.get("publicationPlace", "")}',
                     ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rest_api_sof()
```

To replicate and see Error in json file, please comment `1) Running via Bash Script & hard coding input arguments` and correspondingly uncomment `2) Running from python script with input arguments` and run `$ python file.py`.

Here is the error in my json file after running `$ python file.py`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fi">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">
    <title>Digitaaliset aineistot - Kansalliskirjasto</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow"/>
    <meta name="copyright" content="Kansalliskirjasto. Kaikki oikeudet pidätetään."/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="fLK4q3SMlbeGTQl-tN32ENsBoaAaTlRd8sRbmTxlSBU" />

    <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="7EDEBF53A1C81ABECE44A7A666D94950" />

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Serif+Display&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-10360577-3', 'auto');
    </script>

<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-KF8NK1STFH"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    // see google-analytics.service
</script>

<!-- Matomo -->

<script>
    var _paq = window._paq = window._paq || [];

    

    (function() {
            var u = "https://tilasto.lib.helsinki.fi/";
            _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u + 'matomo.php']);
            _paq.push(['setSiteId', '17']);
            var d = document, g = d.createElement('script'), s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            g.async = true;
            g.src = u + 'matomo.js';
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
        }
    )();

</script>

<noscript><p><img src="https://tilasto.lib.helsinki.fi/matomo.php?idsite=17&amp;rec=1" style="border:0;" alt=""/></p></noscript>

<!-- End Matomo Code --><style type="text/css">[ng-cloak] { display: none !important; }</style>
    <script>
        window.errorHandlerUrl = "/rest/js-error-handler";
        window.commonOptions = {"localLoginEnabled":true,"localRegistrationEnabled":false,"marcOverlayEnabled":true,"opendataEnabled":true,"overrideHeader":"","hakaEnabled":true,"includeExternalResources":true,"legalDepositWorkstation":false,"jiraCollectorEnabled":true,"buildNumber":"8201672f226078f2cefbe8a0025dc03f5d98c25f","searchMaxResults":10000,"showExperimentalSearchFeatures":true,"bindingSearchMaxResults":1000,"excelDownloadEnabled":true,"giosgEnabled":true};
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">.external-resource-alt { display: none !important; }</style>
    </head>

<body class="digiweb">

    <noscript>
    <h3>Sovellus vaatii JavaScriptin.</h3>
    <p>Ole hyvä ja laita selaimesi JavaScript päälle, jos haluat käyttää palvelua.</p>
    <h3>Aktivera Javascript.</h3>
    <p>För att kunna använda våra webbaserade system behöver du ha Javascript aktiverat.</p>
    <h3>This application requires JavaScript.</h3>
    <p>Please turn on JavaScript in order to use the application.</p>
</noscript><app-digiweb></app-digiweb>

    <div id="kk-server-error" style="display: none;">
        <h1 align="center">Järjestelmässä tapahtui virhe.</h1></div>

    <div id="kk-server-page" style="display: none;">
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.language = "fi";
        window.renderId = 1673541833124;
        window.facebookAppId = "465149013631512"
        window.reCaptchaSiteKey = "6Lf7xuASAAAAANNu9xcDirXyzjebiH4pPpkKVCKq";
    </script>

    <script src="/assets/runtime-es2015.f1ac93cb35b9635f0f7e.js" type="module"></script>
            <script src="/assets/runtime-es5.f1ac93cb35b9635f0f7e.js" nomodule></script>
            <script src="/assets/polyfills-es2015.8db02cde19c51f542c72.js" type="module"></script>
            <script src="/assets/polyfills-es5.2273af7ef2cf66cdc0de.js" nomodule></script>
            <script src="/assets/styles-es2015.a539381f703344410705.js" type="module"></script>
            <script src="/assets/styles-es5.a539381f703344410705.js" nomodule></script>
            <script src="" type="module"></script>
            <script src="" type="module"></script>
            <script src="" nomodule></script>
            <script src="/assets/main-es2015.b5796f606e925a9d947d.js" type="module"></script>
            <script src="/assets/main-es5.b5796f606e925a9d947d.js" nomodule></script>
            </body>
</html>
```

Comment: anecdotally, this may be easier with a Python web client library like [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/)

Answer (score 1):

To debug this, I replaced `sof.sh` with a very simple Bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "'%s'\n" "$@"
```

It outputs the following:

```
'myFORMATS=['NEWSPAPER']'
'myQUERY=Rusanen'
'myORDERBY=DATE_DESC'
'myLANG=['FIN']'
'myPubPlace=['Iisalmi', 'Kuopio']'
```

In case it's not obvious, the problem is that Python internally prefers single quotes around the strings in the lists; and so, it produces invalid JSON.

The simple fix is probably to force these values into JSON format so that you don't have to change the rest of the code.

```
import json

...
    subprocess.call(['bash',
                     'sof.sh'] +
                    [x + "=" + json.dumps(params[x]) for x in params.keys()])
```

This produces lists of all the values because your `params` values are all lists. If you don't want the query and language to be lists (i.e. don't want square brackets around them), take away the square brackets around them in the definition of the `params` dict in the Python code.